# Firebase Cloud Messaging notification model

Tags: node.js, flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging

I've implemented the Firebase Cloud Messaging using the firebase_messaging plugin in my flutter app, but there is something I don't understand.
I have this payload in the function to send push notifications on message created:

```
               var payload = {
                                notification: {
                                      title: 'Nuevo mensaje!',
                                      body: `${sender} te ha dejado mensaje ${fecha}`,
                                      icon: 'https://*************.es/wp-content/uploads/2019/11/**************.png',
                                      click_action: 'FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK'
                                       },
                             };
```

Everything worked fine till I tried to get the title and the body this way:

```
onMessage: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
            print("onMessage: $message");
            showDialog(
                context: context,
                builder: (context) => AlertDialog(
                        content: ListTile(
                        title: Text(message['notification']['title']),
                        subtitle: Text(message['notification']['body']),
                        ),
                        actions: <Widget>[
                        FlatButton(
                            child: Text('Ok'),
                            onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).pop(),
                        ),
                    ],
                ),
            );
```

They were null, so I looked on the message and saw that I receive it like this:

> {gcm.message_id: dsadsadasd, google.c.sender.id: dasdsaddcwfewf3,
>   google.c.a.e: 1, aps: {alert: {title:Nuevo mensaje!, body: Ronaldo
>   te ha dejado mensaje: 7 3 2020 15:00}, category:
>   FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK}}

So changing the way I decode the message like:

```
content: ListTile(
            title: Text(message['aps']['alert']['title']),
            subtitle: Text(message['aps']['alert']['body']),
          ),
```

everything works fine, but I wonder why I send "notification: {title:}" but receive aps: {alert: {title:}}. The tutorial I followed seems to receive it normally with the "notification" key. What's going on here? What am I missing? The code works, but I feel like I didn't implemented it the right way.

EDIT: I just tested it on Android and there it decodes the way it was supposed to do:

```
 title: Text(message['notification']['title']),
 subtitle: Text(message['notification']['body']
```

So now I handle it like Platform.isAndroid ? message : message ;
But I want to know whats going on.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it is the reason for your issue but in my cloud functions (should be the same in the app) the payload structure I use has the click_action k:v pair in the data section:

```
const payload = {
        notification: {
          title_loc_key: "notification_title_string",
          body_loc_key: "notification_message_favoriting_string",
          badge: "1",
          sound: "default",
        },
        data: {
          click_action: "FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK",
          rcpntId: recipientId,
          sndrId: senderId, 
        }
      };
```

I think that you need to be putting the data that you want to process with your alert dialogue in the data block. The notification block is about what appears in the device status bar. You will also need the data block for onResume and onLaunch responses to notifications.

Comment: hmm, I'll give it a try, but I don't think I need data to process because I subscribe to topic and when receive message I send the user to notifications screen and there he fetch the data from firebase and can see the new messages.

Comment: Well I tried it, because I had to add some data but it doesn't work. I read that there's an iOS platform specific field in the payload named apns, but still the  notification: {
  }, field is universal and serve to send title and body to both platforms, so I have no idea, why on iOS you receive it in this aps/alert form.

Comment: Ok, I only realised after your edit that your question related to iOS. I have only tested it on Android so far and have the joys of iOS testing to look forward to. Your solution to the issue will therefore help me,so thanks for that. If I come across a reason for this whilst doing the usual wading through docs, Medium posts, SO, Flutter and Firebase forums, etc., I will post it here.